# GDAL - XYZ to GeoTIFF slow

Tags: gdal, qgis

I have an **XYZ** raster file, **1.1GB** in **EPSG:23700 (EOV)**, **50 meters resolution**.

The aim is to create a **GeoTIFF** file to be published via GeoServer (**EPSG:4326**), but I have some performance issues.

If I open the **XYZ file from QGIS (2.14.0, Essen)**, choose **Raster » Conversion » Translate** and start it with the default options, it completes in several minutes, which is acceptable.

But if I copy the generated **gdal_translate** command and run it from CLI, than it takes more than an hour or so.

I've tried `-co "GDAL_CACHEMAX=500"`, `-co "NUM_THREADS=3"`, but has no effect. In the process monitor, the QGIS version uses **1 core** fully (**25% CPU**) and the default max memory of **10MByte**, but the CLI version only **<10%** and **<10Mbyte** mem. The `--degub ON` option shows **"XYZ: New stepX=50.000000000000000"** and hangs there.

I've tried to run it from the QGIS Directory **\bin** folder and the separately downloaded **GDAL** instance (**C:\OSGeo4W64\bin**), same results.

**Windows Server 2012, 16GB RAM, 2,6 GHz 4 core Xenon CPU.**

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's some problem with the environment variables. If I use a modified version of the QGIS startup batch file, it all works as expected.

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
set GDAL_CACHEMAX = 500
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt4\plugins

REM This line changed to run my batch file instead of starting QGIS.
call "d:\gdaltest.bat"
```

Comment: Correction: the only thing needed is the o4w_env.bat to be called before running the processing batch. I'll look into that batch file, where the magic happens (and why it's needed to work in this environment...)